# Convert fixed layout azw3 file, to pdf first or other formats if not possible, with all formatting intact

Tags: epub, calibre, conversion, formatting, fixed-layout

I have an azw3 as described above. It can be converted into epub, using the extension from Calibre "Kindle Unpack", but there are no paragraphs, meaning that the all the words in the txt file is structured like a wall of text. I use SumatraPDF which can read all the azw3, mobi, pdf and epub2 and/or epub3 files with much less effort than Adobe Reader.

Edit: Oh, I forgot to tell you. The azw3 file can also be unpacked into xhtml files.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options for you:

1. AZW3 is just a slightly modified MOBI format. So virtually any (on-line or off-line) solution that can do MOBI -> PDF conversion (with results acceptable by you) should do the trick.
2. Since you can already open AZW3 files directly in SumatraPDF  then I consider installing a virtual printer driver that will be able to print *anything* (from screenshot, image, webpage through any open document) to PDF format. And in most cases (there are many, many options for virtual printers) it will do 1:1 or rather to say WYSIWYG, so with all the formatting etc. intact.

I have never used any of above approaches so this is theoretical suggestion only. But, my friend told me that first options works just fine, only he had to change file name's extension from AZW3 to MOBI to "foul" such on-line converting service.

Comment: It's impossible to print this file. The first option works fine, but it's still just a wall of text.

Comment: In any case, this azw3 fixed layout file can't be viewed with SumatraPDF.

Comment: I can't match your question ("I use SumatraPDF which can read all the azw3") with your comment above ("In any case, this azw3 fixed layout file can't be viewed with SumatraPDF"). If you cannot open your file (with expected layout) in any program on your computer then second suggestion in my answer is out of question. If you can open it then what seems to be the problem with printing on virtual printer? You just press Ctrl+P and print just as you would print it on piece of paper. If printing this AZW3 file is prohibited / blocked then you won't be most likely able to convert it to PDF as well.